# select all items which matches a group by query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query which is used to find duplicates.

```
SELECT Namn, ServerRef
FROM TlsSignal
GROUP BY Namn, ServerRef
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

How do I write a select which returns all rows that match that query (i.e. without the grouping)?

If it was just one field that had to match I would have made a sub select, but I can't figure out how to do it when two different fields must match the result from the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that query to join back to the source table like this:

```
SELECT TlsSignal.*
FROM TlsSignal
JOIN 
    (SELECT Namn, ServerRef
    FROM TlsSignal
    GROUP BY Namn, ServerRef
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS Duplicates
ON TlsSignal.Namn = Duplicates.Namn AND TlsSignal.ServerRef = Duplicates.ServerRef
```

Alternatively, and I'd probably use this method. In SQL Server you can use a `common table expression`:

```
WITH Duplicates_CTE(Namn, ServerRef)
AS
    (SELECT Namn, ServerRef
    FROM TlsSignal
    GROUP BY Namn, ServerRef
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

SELECT TlsSignal.*
FROM TlsSignal
JOIN Duplicates_CTE
    ON TlsSignal.Namn = Duplicates_CTE.Namn 
    AND TlsSignal.ServerRef = Duplicates_CTE.ServerRef
```

Comment: ahh. a simple join. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM TlsSignal T1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Namn
        ,ServerRef
    FROM TlsSignal
    GROUP BY Namn
        ,ServerRef
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS T2 ON T1.Namn = T2.Namn
    AND T1.ServerRef = T2.ServerRef
```